# Como obter a quantidade de registros em uma consulta no SQLite?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, ado.net

Estou listando os registros de uma tabela com o código abaixo:

```
SQLiteCommand comando = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Cadastro " +filtro, conn);
SQLiteDataReader receber = comando.ExecuteReader();
```

Porém antes de listar, preciso verificar se existe registro na tabela.

Como faria para contar os registros da tabela com SQLite e C#?

Comment: É necessário que a contagem seja feita ***antes*** de percorrer os resultados? Porque?

Comment: Então dcastro. A necessidade da contagem é para verificar se existem registros, caso contrário aparecerá uma mensagem "Não existem registros no momento".

Comment: Eu percebo a necessidade de contagem, a minha pergunta nao era acerca disso. A pergunta era acerca da necessidade dessa contagem ser feita ***antes*** da percorrer os resultados (e não *depois* ou *durante*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É impossível saber quantas linhas foram retornadas antes de percorrer o data reader, porque o comando `ExecuteReader` cria o reader **antes** de todas as linhas serem retornadas do servidor.

As linhas vao sendo retornadas à medida que se invoca o método `DbDataReader.Read`.

Logo, a maneira ideal de saber quantas colunas foram retornadas é percorrê-las.

```
var reader = comando.ExecuteReader();

var counter = 0;
while(reader.Read())
{
    counter++;

    // ler linha, transforma-la e guarda-la numa lista, por exemplo
}
```

ou

```
var reader = comando.ExecuteReader();    
var models = new List<Model>();

while(reader.Read())
{
    // ler linha, transforma-la e guarda-la numa lista, por exemplo

    var model = new Model(reader["coluna"]);
    models.Add(model);    
}

var count = models.Count;
```

Comment: Certo. Mas caso eu precise mostrar uma mensagem informando que nenhum registro foi encontrado, como eu faria?

Comment: @Jose.Marcos então, fácil. `if(count ==0) mostrar erro`

Comment: Obrigado dcastro. Vou usar o seu modelo.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer uma query para pegar a quantidade de registros antes de fazer a consulta principal.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Cadastro
```

Após receber o resultado, você pode utilizar a sua lógica verificando se a quantidade retornada é maior que 0.

Comment: Até pensei em fazer isso, mas por ex.: no php usamos o mysqli_num_rows($resultado) para retornar o número de linhas. No sqlite/C# não teria uma opção parecida?

Comment: Entendi, o problema seria como realizar isso no c#, não tenho conhecimento profundo em c#, mas creio que a segunda linha do seu exemplo já te retorne o resultado da consulta, neste SELECT sempre te retornará um único registro (numérico) já com o valor da quantidade de linhas que possui.

Comment: Não há método parecido no SQLite. Faça como foi dito, utilize o SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Cadastro, mas ao executar o comando, utilize o método ExecuteEscalar, acho que é isso... ele vai retornar um resultado apenas. Converta para int e faça a verificação.

Comment: Não há garantia que o resultado de `select count` será igual ao numero de rows retornadas pelo `select *` que o sucede. Linhas podem ser apagadas/inseridas concurrentemente entre ambos os selects.

Answer (score 3):

O que você está tentando fazer não é viável. Não é que não pode fazer (não pode mesmo, diretamente) é que fazer seria um erro. Você está potencialmente provocando um [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101), ou seja, entre uma consulta e outra pode ser que a condição não seja a mesma. Isto é mais ou menos como você verificar se um arquivo existe para abri-lo. Quando for abrir, ele pode não existir mais.

Se você ler o que escreveu na pergunta já terá a solução: "preciso verificar se existe registro na tabela". Então faça isto. A variável `filtro` é o que você precisa verificar? Então está pronto, se não é, adicione à expressão SQL.

Você só deve fazer uma contagem se você precisa da contagem. Claramente você está dizendo que quer outra coisa. Aparentemente você está prejudicando a performance achando que está melhorando. Piorando a robustez. E fazendo algo semanticamente errado.

Mesmo que precise da contagem depois, eu ainda a faria via código C# para evitar a condição de corrida mencionada. Mas aparentemente nem isto você precisa.

Por mais que você queira fazer de outro jeito, estará cometendo um erro. Você pode não gostar desta resposta, mas é a única válida para sua situação é esta.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: +1 Boa explicação, e pela analogia com a leitura de um ficheiro/verificar se o ficheiro existe. Esse é um erro que vejo com demasiada frenquência.

Answer (score 0):

Usei o seguinte código abaixo baseado no CaiqueC e parece que funcionou:

```
SQLiteCommand contar = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT COUNT(*)FROM Cadastro " + filtro, conn);
contar.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

long numeroRegistros = (long)contar.ExecuteScalar();
contar.Dispose();

if(numeroRegistros > 0){
List<DadosGB> listar = new List<DadosGB>();

 while (receber.Read())
 {
    // Mostrar o resultado
}
}else{
MessageBox.Show("Nenhum registro foi encontrado"); 
}
```

Comment: Como eu e o bigown explicamos, esse método é incorrecto e está sujeito a erros de concurrencia.

Comment: Entendi dcastro. Uso muito pouco o C# e estou aprendendo nos erros ; )

Comment: **parece** que funcionou.

Comment: O código do dcastro serviu para o que eu estava precisando. Obrigado a todos!